# Royden's proof that $L^{p_2}\subseteq L^{p_1}$ if $p_1<p_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading the proof of the following theorem:

> Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure and $1\le p_1<p_2\le \infty$.  Then $L^{p_2}(E)\subseteq L^{p_1}(E)$.  Furthermore
> $$\|f\|_{p_1}\le c \| f\|_{p_2}$$
> for all $f\in L^{p_2}(E)$, where $c=[m(E)]^{\frac{p_2-p_1}{p_1p_2}}$ if $p_2<\infty$ and $c=[m(E)]^{1/p_{1}}$ if $p_2=\infty$.

Proof:

> [...] Assume $p_2<\infty$.  Define $p=p_2/p_1>1$ and let $q$ be the conjugate of $p$.  Let $f$ belong to $L^{p_2}(E)$.  Observe that $|f|^{p_1}$ belongs to $L^p(E)$ and $g=\chi_E$ belongs to $L^q(E)$ since $m(E)<\infty$.  [Note: Royden did not originally have $|f|^{p_1}$ but rather $f^{p_1}$.  However, this was corrected in the errata, so I included the correction here.]  Apply Holder's Inequality.  Then
> $$ \int_E|f|^{p_1} = \int_E|f|^{p_1}\cdot g \le \|f\|_{p_2}^{p_1}\cdot \left[ \int_E|g|^q \right]^{1/q} = \|f\|_{p_2}^{p_1}[m(E)]^{1/q}.$$

Now my question is at this first inequality where Holder's is applied.  I certainly agree that we could obtain at this stage

$$ \int_E|f|^{p_1}\cdot g \le \||f|^{p_1}\|_{p_2} \cdot \left[ \int_E|g|^q \right]^{1/q}$$

But the move made here seems to assume $\||f|^{p_1}\|_{p_2}=\|f\|^{p_1}_{p_2}$.  But this doesn't seem obvious or established earlier in the text.  Am I misunderstanding what's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are applying Holder's inequality with the conjugate exponents $p:=\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ and $q$. YOu seem to think we're applying it to $p_2$ and $q$ (which is wrong since they aren't even conjugate exponents). Since $1<p,q<\infty$, all the norms are defined using integrals, so:
\begin{align}
\int_E|f|^{p_1}\cdot 1&\leq \||f|^{p_1}\|_p \cdot \|1\|_q \tag{Holder's inequality}\\
&=\left(\int_E(|f|^{p_1})^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \cdot [m(E)]^{1/q}\\
&=\left(\int_E|f|^{p_2}\right)^{\frac{p_1}{p_2}}\cdot [m(E)]^{1/q}\\
&=\left[\left(\int_E|f|^{p_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{p_2}}\right]^{p_1}\cdot [m(E)]^{1/q}\\
&=\|f\|_{p_2}^{p_1}\cdot [m(E)]^{1/q}
\end{align}
These intermediate steps were "obvious enough" to be left as details to be verified by the reader, and not explicitly mentioned in the form of a theorem/lemma, because really, it's just a matter of checking if one understands the definition of $L^p$ norms.